# Html.DropDownListFor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I render Html.DropDownListfor in my JavaScript and than when i go to browser to check how Output looks like and i can see there is extra double quotes.
How can i archive this in better way?! Thanks in advance :)
Output is look like this:

```
<select class="&quot;form-control" border-input&quot;="" data-val="&quot;true&quot;" data-val-number="&quot;The" field="" selectedrmatype="" must="" be="" a="" number.&quot;="" id="&quot;SelectedRMAType&quot;" name="&quot;SelectedRMAType&quot;" style="&quot;background:none;&quot;"><option value="&quot;&quot;">- Vælg årsag -</option>
<option value="&quot;1&quot;">Forkert vare bestilt (fejlbestilling)</option>
<option value="&quot;2&quot;">Forkert vare modtaget (fejllevering)</option>
<option value="&quot;3&quot;">Modtaget for meget/lidt (fejllevering)</option>
<option value="&quot;4&quot;">Vare fysisk skadet ved modtagelse (transportskade)</option>
<option value="&quot;5&quot;">Vare virker ikke ved modtagelse (første dag)</option>
<option value="&quot;6&quot;">Defekt vare (efter første dag)</option>
<option value="&quot;7&quot;">Prisfejl</option>
<option value="&quot;8&quot;">Andet</option>
</select>
```

DropDownlistfor:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedRMAType, Model.RMAType, "- Select -", new { @class = "form-control border-input", @id = "SelectedRMAType", @style = "background:none;" })
```

DropDownListFor in JS:

```
 rows += '<td>' + '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedRMAType, Model.RMAType, "- Select -", new { @class = "form-control border-input", @id = "SelectedRMAType", @style = "background:none;" }).ToHtmlString())' + '</td>'
```

Controller:

```
public  ActionResult FindRMA(RMAHistory oodvm) {

    oodvm.RMAType = new SelectList(data.RMAType, "ID", "RMASager").ToList();

    return View(oodvm);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<SelectListItem> RMAType { set; get; }
public int? SelectedRMAType { set; get; }
```

Comment: It would help to know what is populated in  Model.RMAType and how you are populating it.

Comment: Razor engine is encoding your dynamic js. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you using HTML helpers in js?

Comment: @adiga i understand is encoding but its generate some extra characters which is invalid

Comment: @MikeS i updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(...)
```

to

```
@Html.Raw(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this;

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RMAType).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.YourListValue(), Value = i.YourListKey() }))
```